# Getting JShell Error: ';' expected for basic HelloWorld.java program

Tags: java, jshell

Only ever used IDEs for developing in Java and wanted to learn how to use JShell but I'm getting the following error for a basic hello world example and anything else I try. Don't understand where the ';' error is coming from.
|javac HelloWorld.java
|  Error:
|  ';' expected
|  javac HelloWorld.java;

code for HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

---

Comment: Unable to correlate with the command line used and the code shared, how was that executed using jshell?

Answer (score 1):

You don't compile in [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jshell.htm#JSWOR-GUID-C337353B-074A-431C-993F-60C226163F00), you can add the main method and then call it

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
 }

 main(null);
```

> The following examples shows a method being defined and the method run:
>
> ```
> jshell> String grade(int testScore) {
>  .....
>  jshell> grade(88)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two different "hello world" programs:

```
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ java hello.java
Hello World from Java
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ cat hello.java
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World from Java");
  }
}


thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ jshell hello.jsh
Hello World
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ ./hello.jsh 
jshell 11.0.1
Hello World
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ 
thufir@dur:~/jshell$ cat hello.jsh 
//usr/bin/env jshell --show-version "$0" "$@"; exit $?
System.out.println("Hello World")
/exit
thufir@dur:~/jshell$
```

the `.jsh` or `JShell` script is executable so can run a few ways.  Hope that helps.